# Why Newtonsoft.Json cannot resolve symbol 'DeserializeObject'?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json lib in my class, but I got this error:

[image]

Code:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes), typeof(VerificationResult)) as VerificationResult;

return results != null && results.Success
        ? CaptchaResultCode.Valid
        : CaptchaResultCode.InValid;
```

The project including the lib also `using Newtonsoft.Json;` is located in my class. Does somebody know that happened? :)

Comment: Is this intellisense error or the same happens on build?

Comment: What's the version of the package you're referencing?

Comment: @GuruStron No, is not. I haven't got errors after build :)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride it is a last version package - 12.0.3

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   var results =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerificationResult>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

Link https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm